# PayPal IPN Custom Form data

Tags: php, mysql, forms, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to get several additional data to insert in my database after the IPN is verified. I get the default form fields as defined by PayPal correctly, however if I try to send custom ones they won't be received.

Here's my IPN method, right after $insertTransaction I've noted with a comment that I want to add several custom values to another table (orders) which I get from the same form where the user is buying them:

```
        public function ipn()
    {
        // CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
        define("DEBUG", 1);

// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
        define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);


        define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");


// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2)
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data

        if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
            $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        } else {
            $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        }

        $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
        if ($ch == FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

        if(DEBUG == true) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
        }

// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.

//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
        {
            if(DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            exit;

        } else {
            // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
            if(DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);

                // Split response headers and payload
                list($headers, $res) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $res, 2);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
        }

// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            if($_POST['payment_status'] != "Completed")
            {
                exit;
            }
            /*if(urldecode($_POST['receiver_email']) == 'anooxy@gmail.com')
            {
                exit;
            }*/

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE txn_id = :txn_id");
            $stmt->bindValue(':txn_id', $_POST['txn_id']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $numRows = $stmt->rowCount();


            if($numRows != 0)
            {
                exit;
            }

            $stmt->closeCursor();

            $insertTransaction = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO transactions(txn_id, receiver, payer, item_name, payment_amount, payment_currency, payment_status, users_id)
                                                     VALUES(:txn_id, :receiver, :payer, :item_name, :payment_amount, :payment_currency, :payment_status, 6)');
            $insertTransaction->execute(array(
                ':txn_id' => $_POST['txn_id'],
                ':receiver' => $_POST['receiver_email'],
                ':payer' => $_POST['payer_email'],
                ':item_name' => $_POST['item_name'],
                ':payment_amount' => $_POST['mc_gross'],
                ':payment_currency' => $_POST['mc_currency'],
                ':payment_status' => $_POST['payment_status']
            ));

            // I WANT TO DO AN INSERTION OF SEVERAL CUSTOM VARIABLES TO ANOTHER TABLE (ORDERS)

            // check whether the payment_status is Completed
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            // process payment and mark item as paid.

            // assign posted variables to local variables
            //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
            //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
            //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
            //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
            //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
            //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
            //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
            //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

            if(DEBUG == true) {

                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
        } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation
            // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
            if(DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
        }
    }
```

My form HTML is:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" class="paypal-button" target="_top">
                            <input type="hidden" name="button" value="buynow">
                            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="10 Appuntamenti">
                            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
                            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
                            <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="10">
                            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="IT">
                            <input type="hidden" name="env" value="www.sandbox">
                            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://spazio.glend.me/utente/compra">
                            <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://spazio.glend.me/utente/ipn">
                            <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="Y8WPHSYX7692E">
                            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="JavaScriptButton_buynow">
                            <button type="submit" class="paypal-button large">Buy Now</button>
                        </form>
```

I tried to add custom input fields to no avail. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your ipn function, I don't see you trying to access the $_POST variable `custom`?

Also, in your form, the `custom` field is empty:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
```

Double-check [the manual](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) and make sure that you're using the custom field correctly. If you have multiple values, use a delimiter such as "-".